# Passing data to segue from annotation?

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation, cloudkit

I have a mapView with annotations that are created using data from CloudKit. I use the info button from the annotation to call the segue when the button is tapped.

I know that I can pass title and subtitle easily like this..

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let detailTitle = annotationView.annotation.title

    performSegueWithIdentifier("fromMap", sender: self)

}
```

My issue is that I need to send more than just the data that is inside the MKAnnotation view.  I have a few other fields from the CloudKit records that I need to pass along through the segue to the detail controller, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do that.

It's easy to do with a tableView because you have the indexPath info, but you don't have that from an annotation as far as I can tell.

I've looked through all the posts and info I could find online, but I'm still stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tuple` just to send more than one object and catch them from the target view controller

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
  let detailTitle = annotationView.annotation.title
  performSegueWithIdentifier("fromMap", sender: (annotation.title, annotation.subtitle, annotation.address))
}
```

Comment: Seems like it could work, will try it.  How would I send data that isn't part of the annotation, but is part of the same record in CloudKit?
For example, the CK record contains data like rating info that I want to send, but wasn't ever used in the annotation because it wasn't needed there.

Comment: I think this blog has just the information you need. http://nshipster.com/cloudkit/

Comment: let greatID = CKRecordID(recordName: "GreatPlace")

publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(greatID) { fetchedPlace, error in
    // handle errors here
}

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Thanks so much.